# Синхронизация данных с помощью аккаунта

Tags: android-sdk, android, синхронизация, java

Есть свой аккаунт в android системе, с настроенным методом синхронизации. Как принудительно, из кода, вызвать синхронизацию в любой момент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно вызвать RequestSync. Читайте [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118450/). Также, если галочка снята,  то синхронизацию можно все таки с приложения [вызвать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529072/how-synchronization-with-syncadapter-works-on-android/5539385#5539385).